# Does coffee affect people from all races the same?

Tags: caffeine

I strongly assume that, if the looks from people all over the world vary, then also there metabolic system should vary and wonder, if there are noticeable differences how caffeine affects people from different cultures.

I tried to look it up on the Internet, however I didn't find much, so I would assume there is not much of a difference. But surely there are people, who know a lot more than me in this field. Therefore I were very happy for any constructive comment.

Answer (score 4):

I do not consider myself an expert, but I do remember one study done on this. In "The world of caffeine: The science culture and world's most popular drug," do indeed hypothesize that Japanese (and Asians in general) metabilise coffee slower than other races. So the effects of caffeine are felt longer.

Comment: That would be really cool :) 
I will check up on that! I wish I were Asian.. being Asian seems to be so advantageous..

Comment: Would you post a reference or link to that paper? Is it [this one](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM200104193441617)? There seem to be several titles with very similar names.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the one.